# Area of the quarter circle with SymPy Integrate?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I would like to evaluate the following integral using SymPy:

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
a = symbols('a', positive=True)
expr = sqrt(a**2 - x**2)
integrate(expr, (x, 0, pi/2))
```

What I would expect as an outcome is the area of the quarter circle (i.e., a^2*pi/4). Unfortunately, SymPy does not provide this result. When considering

```py
integrate(expr, x)
```

I obtain the correct indefinite integral but when adding the limits it does not work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit should be `a` if that is the radius and you are working in Cartesian coordinates:

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
a = symbols('a', positive=True)
expr = sqrt(a**2 - x**2)
integrate(expr, (x, 0, a))
```

That gives:

```
   2
π⋅a 
────
 4
```